# How to Assign Values to a Vector Based on a Logical Expression in R

Tags: r, function, vector

I'm trying to write the following function:

```
f <- function(q, r) {
  for(i in seq(from = (1 - r), to = (r - 1), by = 1)){
  s <- r + i;
    if (q %% s == 0) {
    here(s)
    }
  }
}
```

However, where I have "here," I'd like those values of s that meet the criterion specified by the "if" statement above it, so that I may perform operations on it (take max and min values, and whatnot), i.e. a vector of the form:

v <- c(those values of s that meet the criterion stipulated by if statement)

I'm sure this is relatively simple, but this is the first function I've tried to write in R, so bear with me, if you could. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand in your code, you want to create a vector from `(1-r+r)` to `(r-1+r)` and then if the values of that vector are divisible by q, then you want to apply a function to them.

I created a vector of only the numbers that meet the condition (by sub-setting with the `TRUE/FALSE` vector) and then applied the function only to those that met the condition.

I hope this code correctly interprets your function.

```
f <- function(q, r) {
    s <- seq(1, 2*r-1, by=1)
    ind <- ifelse(q %% s == 0, TRUE, FALSE) 
    result <- here(s[ind])
   return(result)
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks.